# Existential Instantiation and its restrictions

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am really struggling to get to grips with Enderton's Existential Instatiation. I asked a question yesterday and had to delete it shortly after because it was wrong... Hopefully, today I'll be better at narrowing down what bothers me.

Basically, trying to use a notation that is self-explanatory, Enderton is saying that $\Sigma, \varphi(c) \vdash \psi$ implies that $\Sigma, \exists x \varphi(x) \vdash \psi$. The restriction is that $c$ is a new symbol that basically doesn't appear anywhere...

Now, my problem with this is the proof. He uses a theorem that he proves in the previous page and he calls it "Generalization on constants". He proves that if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi(c)$, then there exists a variable $y$ such that $\Gamma \vdash \forall y \varphi(y)$.

In the first step of his proof, he takes a deduction of $\Gamma \vdash \varphi(c)$, replaces $c$ with $y$ in every formula, and proves that the resulting sequence is a deduction of $\Gamma \vdash \varphi(y)$. In order to do that, he takes every formula and says it must either be a logical axiom, a member of $\Gamma$ or an application of modus ponens.

Specifically, if it is a logical axiom, then it stays a logical axiom if you replace $c$ with $y$. And I agree with that, but what happens when we get out of the pure logical theory and add some non-logical axioms? I don't think there is a rule that restricts how you can write axioms, so if this theorem is all we have, each time a new theory is defined, we need to prove that all of its axioms have this property before we can use existential instantiation?

For example, I could add an axiom to the Peano system to add a new constant to define the number $1$. It would look like this: $1=S(0)$. It looks like a pretty harmless thing to do. Let me simulate a silly dialogue between me and Enderton:

Me: I claim that $\Sigma, \varphi(1) \vdash \psi$ implies $\Sigma, \exists x \varphi(x) \vdash \psi$.

Enderton: No! That's clearly wrong. $1$ is not a generic constant, so you can't do that. You must ensure that your constant does not appear in your non-logical axioms.

Me: OK, then my $c$ cannot appear in my non-logical axioms, but surely $c+0=c$ is an axiom for any $c$ I can come up with, so I would never be able to use any $c$.

Does anybody have a view on this? Is there a flaw in my reasoning? Do you think there is a way to enunciate existential instantiation without having to run through the axioms of every new theory we can come up with? Because I don't think there is anything you could write in the non-logical axioms that would harm your right to use existential instantiation.

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't mention my personal attempt so "solve" this. I think the aforementioned theorem should have the limitation that $c$ cannot appear in any axiom or, if it does appear in an axiom, for every variable $x$, the formula built replacing $c$ with $x$ should also be an axiom. I think these limitations would make that theorem general. And, incidentally, the same limitation could be applied to $\Gamma$ as well and it would be less restrictive than the current one that says that $c$ cannot occur in $\Gamma$ at all.

Comment: Thank you, Mauro. I had thought about $\Gamma$ being PA, but even then, we are saying that we would not be able to work in a theory that uses axiom schemas. It is still true that if my axiom is some schema $x+0=x$, then technically $c+0=c$ is an axiom and therefore $c$ occurs in $\Gamma$. Basically, depending on how we choose our axioms we may or may not be able to satisfy the assumptions of this theorem.

Comment: I understand how you can go from $x+0=x$ to $PA \vdash c+0=c$. However, what I'm saying is that these theorems only work if you decide that $x+0=x$ is an axiom that only works for $x$ and then you have to prove $c+0=c$. If we had said that $x+0=x$ is an axiom schema that applies to any term, we would have violated the conditions of the theorem. Even if in truth, there would be no harm in doing an existential instantiation. What I'm saying is that I believe this theorem imposes unnecessary restrictions to what you can or cannot have in your axioms.

Comment: Let me try. Enderton says that all tautologies are axioms, which by his own admission is overkill, but let's suppose $A \rightarrow A$ is an axiom. This actually means that $x=5 \rightarrow x=5$ or $y=z \rightarrow y=z$ are all axioms, with no deductions involved. If I decided to do the same and create an alternative PA where there is an axiom of type $t+0=t$ for every term, suddenly for every $c$, $c+0=c$ would be an axiom and not a theorem. In a system like that, just because I chose to define my axioms that way, Enderton would not let me use EI.